# Call Derived class method when it's known as shared_ptr<Basic>

Tags: c++, oop, templates, casting

I strongly believe that this is very common object-oriented question, but hard googling didn't give me an answer. I hope, that someone could point me to the *right* way how to escape from my deadlock. I try to know and use standard techniques and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Here is a nutshell:

```
class A {
protected:
    int _A;
public:
    virtual void commonMethod() = 0;
    void methodForMember_A();
}

class B : public A {
protected:
    int _B;
public:
    virtual void commonMethod()
    void methodForMember_B();
}

class C : public B {
protected:
    int _C;
public:
    virtual void commonMethod()
    void methodForMember_C();
}

class Basic {
protected:
    // B or C instance
    shared_ptr<A> _smth;
public:
    Basic(shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) : _smth(a_ptr);
    // calls A/B/C->commonMethod();
    void commonMethod();
}

// Which works with B
class MoreSpecific : public Basic {
public:
    MoreSpecific(shared_ptr<B> b_ptr) : Basic(b_ptr);
    // calls b->methodForMemberB();
    void specificMethod();
}
```

The question is in the `specificMethod()` where I wish to call `_smth->methodForMemberB()`.

I can see the following ways:

1. Casting in all `specificMethods()`? (it seems to me that casting is kind of a lifeboat and has to be used in really complicated cases)
2. Time for templates? (Not sure that templates will be appropriate here)
3. Design is absolutely wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in specificMethod(), when the object is _not_ B instance, what is expected to happen?

Comment: object at least B(or C as maximum) because I can't make an instance of A (due to pure abstract '=0' commonMethod)

Comment: @danilabagroff But later you (or someone else) could add a `class D : public A` and construct a `Basic` using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the moment you are using/relying on `Basic` to store your `B` pointer, you are losing the information that it's not just an `A` instance. You are not following the (Liskov) inheritance principle in this case!

There are several ways around that. Templates are one way, but it depends on the circumstances and in this case, a more "interface oriented" solution might be appropriate. The problem in this case is that you are storing your `B` in the base class, so that's what we'll avoid here. Instead, use an abstract interface:

```
class Basic {
protected:
    virtual shared_ptr<A> getPtr () = 0; 
public:
    // calls A/B/C->commonMethod();, uses getPtr ()
    void commonMethod();
};

// Which works with B
class MoreSpecific : public Basic {
protected:
    // Store and implement interface for base classes
    shared_ptr<B> b_ptr;
    shared_ptr<A> getPtr () {return b_ptr;}
public:
    MoreSpecific(shared_ptr<B> b_ptr) : b_ptr(b_ptr);
    // calls b->methodForMemberB();
    void specificMethod();
};
```

If you really need a class that stores a bare A ptr, you can let that class implement the `Basic` interface to. The general lesson to be learned is this: abstract interfaces without data members are a good idea!

Comment: Thank you for the lesson. The answer boils down to "abstract interfaces without data members are a good idea".

Answer (score 2):

If the `MoreSpecific` interface is only valid for `B` instances, you must make sure to not set `A` objects to `Basic::_smth`. You can do this using a base class template

```
template<typename T>
class BasicBase {
protected:
    shared_ptr<T> _smth;
public:
    BasicBase (shared_ptr<T> a_ptr) : _smth(a_ptr);

    void commonMethod();
}

typedef BasicBase <A> Basic;


// Which works with B only
class MoreSpecific : public Basic<B> {
public:
    MoreSpecific(shared_ptr<B> b_ptr) : Basic(b_ptr);
    // calls b->methodForMemberB();
    void specificMethod();
}
```

Comment: One more good solution with templates. Unfortunately, not enough reputation for a vote :(